# Bind list from FormView to model in ASP.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, list, formview

For a large fillin form I use the asp.net FormView for the magic databinding to my model. In this model I've a property called Rides (shown below), which exposes a list, which I obviously not want to be replaced entirely. So I made it readonly.

However, this way I can't use the databinding features anymore. Is there a common solution for this problem?

```
public IList<Ride> Rides
{
    get
    {
        if (this._rides == null)
        {
            this._rides = new List<Ride>();
        }

        return this._rides;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem when you say you can't use DataBinding with it? What happens? Do you get any error message or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monty,
Take a look at a class named BindingList. Binding list enables two-way binding. You can create it from Yor collection in code and bidn it to the datasource property of the FormView. I think this is what You want.
Also by exposing IList YOU have not made this thing read-only. I can recast to the List and I can modify You items all the way. If You really want to expose rides as read-only return IEnumerable and return not a List by a ReadOnlyCollection... recasting list to the other class wont' help.

Comment: I guess this will do, as close it can get I think. Of course I know exposing as IList won't make it read-only. Will have a try on this, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I see that You meant, that the property is a get-only. My bad:)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the databinding, instead of <%# Bind("PropertyName")%> use <%# Eval("PropertyName")%>,
as Bind is usually for 2 way binding & Eval is usually for evaluation of the underlying datasources, Bind will be handy when you have a setter as well.
Hope this sheds enough light & you will find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it's my purpose to be able to use the property rides also in the FormView. And preferably I'd like the property to be databound (<%# Bind("PropertyName")%> instead of <%# Eval("PropertyName")%>).

Answer (score 0):

Wild stab in the dark, don't know if this will work but I guess you can try...

How about putting the setter (set) back in the property, but make it assign to itself?

eg.

```
set
{
    this._rides = this._rides;  // Rather than this._rides = value;
}
```

This would mean the value is untouchable from the property, if a set operation is attempted it won't do any damage and should still bind...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it won't work... This way the DataBind() method still can't bind the value back to its source.